# Malformed Node or String with Dynamodb Returned item

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have been experimenting with DynamoDB in AWS and have decided it's the wrong tool for me.  While working in AWS, I uploaded a large number of records to the system that I am now trying to retrieve using Python.  I admit, I'm completely new to Python and what I've cobbled together is from examples found around the internet.  I'm working with Office 365 Audit logs that have many fields and when I retrieve them from Dynamo, I found that decimal fields are coming back as `decimal('1')`.

```
{
  'ItemType': 'File',
  'SourceFileName': 'xxx',
  'UserKey': 'xxx',
  'RecordType': Decimal('6'),
  'UserId': 'xxx',
  'ClientIP': 'xxx',
  'CorrelationId': 'xxx',
  'ObjectId': 'xxx',
  'Version': Decimal('1'),
  'Site': 'xxx',
  'WebId': 'xxx',
  'SourceFileExtension': 'js',
  'SiteUrl': 'xxx',
  'Workload': 'SharePoint',
  'SourceRelativeUrl': 'xxx',
  'EventSource': 'SharePoint',
  'ListId': 'xxx',
  'OrganizationId': 'xxx',
  'Operation': 'FileAccessed',
  'UserAgent': 'xxx',
  'ListItemUniqueId': 'xxx',
  'CreationTime': '2019-07-26T21:54:45',
  'UserType': Decimal('0'),
  'Id': 'xxx',
  'CustomUniqueId': False
}
```

In troubleshooting, I found this handy function that converts Decimal('0') to an actual decimal

```
class DecimalEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):

        if isinstance(o, decimal.Decimal):
            if o % 1 > 0:
                return float(o)
            else:
                return int(o)
        return super(DecimalEncoder, self).default(o)
```

and this function is called

```
response = table.scan(Limit=10)
for i in response['Items']:
    d = ast.literal_eval((json.dumps(i, cls=DecimalEncoder)))
```

For the most part this works fine, unless i has a boolean field (like the example above). Then I get this error

```
malformed node or string: <_ast.Name object at 0x04B3F778>
```

As far as I understand with Python, the boolean values of True and False are capitalized correctly.. I considered adding the the DecimalEncoder default method but this wouldn't do much since it's literally returning the same value

```
elif isinstance(o,bool):
    return True if o else False
```

I did find by removing the key, I got no error

```
if 'CustomUniqueId' in i:
    del i['CustomUniqueId']
```

However, don't want to lose this field. I'm at a loss as to how to resolve this.

Comment: can you add `type(o)` to check the exact type of CustomUniqueId?

Comment: @HoratiuJeflea, the type comes out as <class 'bool'> when I calle `print(type(i['CustomUniqueId']))`

Comment: I mean in the DecimalEncoder, the o

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are converting your Python object to a JSON string (i.e. the `json.dumps` command) and then trying to interpret that string as Python dictionary (the `ast.literal_eval` takes a string and tries to run it as Python code).

A python dictionary looks very similar to a JSON object but they are not 100% compatible.  In JSON, boolean is presented as `true` and `false` and in Python it's represented as `True` and `False`.

I way to solve this would be to use `json.loads` which reads a JSON string and converts it into a Python equivalent:

```
d = json.loads((json.dumps(i, cls=DecimalEncoder)))
```

That being said, this seems like a lot of hoops/processing to convert Decimal class to native floats and would recommend just using Decimal directly or converting to a float (i.e. `float(d['RecordType'])`) if you need to pass them to something that expects a float.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up solving the problem a slightly different way.  I just used the eval function.  `s = json.dumps(i,cls=DecimalEncoder)`  `d = eval(s)`